# Confusing netty IllegalAccessErrror 4.1.5.Final

Tags: netty, riak

I've started seeing an error in production that's new to me.  It looks like the Java Riak client driver hit an error and then I've been spammed with thousands of errors from netty.

This is the stack trace I'm seeing:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: io/netty/channel/AdaptiveRecvByteBufAllocator$HandleImpl/
at io.netty.channel.AdaptiveRecvByteBufAllocator.newHandle(AdaptiveRecvByteBufAllocator.java:180)/
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.recvBufAllocHandle(AbstractChannel.java:434)/
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:110)/
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:610)/
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:551)/
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:465)/
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:437)/
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)/
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)/
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Reading the netty code base, this looks like an object instantiation:

```
@Override
public Handle newHandle() {
    return new HandleImpl(minIndex, maxIndex, initial);
}
```

I first see it in my logs right after I saw this exception:

```
Operation onException() channel: id:306028938 riakts.service.consul:8087 java.lang.IllegalAccessError: 
tried to access class io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7 from class io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe
```

I'm really quite lost on how that might be causing an IllegalAccessError.  Any guidance on what could be causing this exception or how to handle it?  I get the strong feeling if I bounce my production application it'll go away, but that feels pretty hacky as a response and I was hoping to do better.

Comment: Thats very strange... never sow such an error. Do you use some special ClassLoader or running in some special environment like a container etc ?